# Reactivate a terminated Lync conversation with the Lync API

Tags: api, state, lync

Using the Lync API with UI Suppression Mode enabled, is it possible to reactivate a one-on-one conversation that has been terminated? In my app, currently, if a user tries to send a message when the conversation state is terminated, I create a new conversation and invite the other user into it. It would be nice if there was a simple way to just reactivate the conversation that was terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Once a conversation is terminated, AFAIK, it's terminated for ever: you can never re-create it.

However, if your application was keeping track of conversations and storing information about them as they terminated, then you could perform this functionality yourself. If a user sends a message and you know of an existing conversation with this user which has since been terminated, you could show the terminated conversation information, whilst connecting the user to the new conversation. To the users of your application it will look like the conversation was never terminated.